# Cookies - date expires doesn't work, when the browser is closed the cookies are cleared

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to save user email for 1 year in cookies, but when the browser is closed the cookies are deleted. Here is the code I try to use:

```
document.cookie = "userEmail=" + email;
document.cookie = "expires=Wed, 31 Oct 2019 11:00:00 GMT";
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with `max-age` to store cookies. https://mrcoles.com/blog/cookies-max-age-vs-expires/