# Why was `Max-Age` introduced for cookies when we already had `Expires`?

Tags: http, cookies

Cookies have two attributes (`Max-Age` and `Expires`) that seem to serve identical purposes, namely specifying when a given cookie will expire.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes), `Expires`:

> Indicates the maximum lifetime of the cookie as an HTTP-date timestamp. See Date for the required formatting.

And `Max-Age`:

> Indicates the number of seconds until the cookie expires. A zero or negative number will expire the cookie immediately. If both Expires and Max-Age are set, Max-Age has precedence.

To me this sounds like they're completely synonymous, the only difference being the format in which the expiration date is expressed; with `Expires` specifying an actual date-time, and `Max-Age` specifying a time span.

It seems like `Expires` actually predates `Max-Age`, and `Max-Age` was introduced much later, but why? That's my question. What shortcoming does `Expires` have that `Max-Age` looks to rectify? And when should one be preferred over the other? If the only thing that's different about `Max-Age` is **how** it expresses the expiration date, then its introduction seems pretty pointless, doesn't it?

To my surprise, I couldn't actually find any relevant information on this, it seems as though I'm the only one for whom this is a question mark, which I find strange, so tell me if I'm missing something.

Note that my question isn't strictly about the technical difference between the two attributes (there are already questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70715904/7734384) that cover this), I'm specifically curious about the **reason** and the motive behind the introduction of `Max-Age`, when `Expires` already existed and did fundamentally the same thing.

Comment: How is this "opinion-based"? I'm asking a perfectly objective question. It seems like whoever decides these things just refuses to read the questions properly and actually understand them, for some unfathomable reason.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio. The problem with a _“Why?”_ questions like this one is that the answers they typically get are primarily opinion-based —just like the the answer this question has already received. The only people who could actually answer this question are the people who wrote the specification that introduced the Max-Age parameter. Others here can generally only speculate about what rationale the people who wrote the specification might have had.

Comment: @sideshowbarker The answer that my question has received doesn't actually answer my question, which is why I haven't marked it as the accepted answer. The fact that the answer is inadequate and is opinion-based doesn't make the question opinion-based. My question was fairly specific: Why was the `Max-Age` cookie attribute introduced? This question has an *objective* answer, and as such cannot be "opinion-based".

Comment: @sideshowbarker Furthermore, the claim that "The only people who could actually answer this question are the people who wrote the specification that introduced the Max-Age parameter." makes no sense whatsoever. Things like this are decided upon based on technical/objective reasons, that's like saying "The only people who could actually answer the question of 'Why was `let` introduced in JavaScript when we already had `var`' are the people who wrote the specification." That is an absurd claim, quite clearly.

Comment: If you hope to get better answers to this question than the unsatisfactory answer this one has already received, consider re-titling it and re-wording it. Because as it’s currently worded, it’s not likely to receive any answers you’re likely to find satisfactory. See the discussion and advice in the answer at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio/323382#323382. Maybe a title such as, _“What’s a specific scenario in which Max-Age solves a problem that can’t be solved by Expires?”_

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use `Max-Age`. Think about what happens when the frontend and backend somehow (accidentally) use different timezones. It's less error-prone imo, but for the sake of backwards compatibility you should set the `Expires` attribute too. Also if some of your logic in your code relies on the expiration of the cookie, you should clearly use `Expires`.